# How to inhibit dashboard and profile management access to normal users?

Tags: wp-admin, user-access

I am developing a site using Wordpress, phpbb3 and WP phpbb Bridge. Users have to manage their profile through phpbb3 and I would like to inhibit normal users access to page mysite.com/wp-admin/ .

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-hide-dashboard/
might be what you are looking for perhaps?

Comment: Thank you @Derek. I forgot to describe in my question that not only I would like to inhibit users the access to dashboard but also to their profile management. So the plugin you linked me is nice for one requirement but it misses the fact that actually it redirects to profile management page.